# Цикл: Вычислить сумму N слагаемых заданного вида

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста выполнить задание. Не могу понять как это всё написать через код.

Вот задание:

При некоторых заданных x, N и E, определяемых вводом, вычислить:
а) Сумму N слагаемых заданного вида;
б) сумму тех слагаемых,которые по абсолютной величине E.
Для случая b выполнить суммирование для двух значений E, отличающихся на порядок, и при этом определить количество слагаемых, включенных в сумму. Сравнить результаты с точным значением функции, для которой данная сумма определяет приближенное значение при х , лежащим в интервале (-R,R).

Вот формула: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В первом случае подойдёт цикл for, во втором можно while

Answer (score 1):

а) N-слагаемых написать довольно легко. Используйте for от 1 до N включительно и накапливайте сумму слагаемых вида x^i/i!, где i-счётчик цикла. Да, начальное значение суммы = 1.
б) Накапливайте сумму, пока слагаемое x^i/i! не станет меньше либо равно Е. Понадобится цикл while. Заодно накопите и кол-во слагаемых.
Точное значение функции вычислите с помощью встроенной функции библиотеки cmath, а потом найдите разницу с приближёнными значениями.

Comment: @ИгорьЛещенко Только не вздумайте писать отдельно функцию для факториала, и вычислять член как `pow(x,n)/factorial(n)`. Подумайте, как вычислить `n+1`-й член, зная `n`-ый...